# I want to load an image using Picasso from a file path

Tags: android

I want to load an image from a file path which I have already defined, but don't want to instantiate another file object since I have already defined the path when saving the image.
I have tried retrieving the image with:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(filename).into(image_tv);
```

This is my code for saving the image;

```
Bitmap bitMapImg;
void saveImage() {
    File filename;
    try {
        String path = 
       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();
        filename = new 
        File(path+"/folder/subfolder/image.jpg");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        bitMapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this 
Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse("file://" + yourFilePath).into(imageView);